# MySQL: What does "KEY" stand for when creating a table?

Tags: mysql, kohana

This code extract is from database.sql file that comes with KohanaJobs app.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`role_id`),
  KEY `fk_role_id` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `last_active` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `contents` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`session_id`),
  KEY `last_active` (`last_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Why just `KEY` has been used above? Is it just to imply that they are used as FKs?

Comment: why the display width of 10 if you're not using zerofill ? why not just declare it as: user_id int unsigned not null ? oh, and why the back-ticks too ???

Comment: @f00 - sorry didn't get what you mean?

Comment: @f00 - Thanks for that site. I'll use it for my future code snippets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'KEY' line is simply telling MySQL that the table should have an **index** on the 'last_active' field.

Foreign keys in MySQL are defined using via '[FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)', although this definition is not honoured unless you're using InnoDB as the storage engine.

For more information (I'd recommend a read to be honest), you should take a look at the full [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) syntax page.

Comment: thanks for the link. I googled for this but all I found was FOREIGN KEY definition not just KEY.

Answer (score 5):

KEY when used there is just another word for INDEX.

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

[(Source)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: can we have multiple `KEY`s for each Foreign Key columns?